# Checking Accepted Answers by query on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

Actually I was counting total accepted answers to earn `Unsung Hero` badge.

So for that I want to fetch below columns by query,

`Total Answer` - `Accepted Answer` - `Zero Score Accepted Answer` -  `Percentage Accepted`

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

Can anyone please help me to check my total accepted answers by composing a new query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)?

Comment: Why not just search for existing queries instead of writing one from scratch? Like [this one for example](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45726/what-percentage-of-my-answers-are-accepted).

Comment: @JonW - sorry but I was not able to find such query. also  I've updated my question to find with `Zero Score Accepted Answer`

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/pm/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns